# Retain rows in dataframe that appear in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with many rows. I wish to retain rows only if the columns have values specified in a list.

```
df.head()

'id' 'col1' 'col2' 'col3
row1  A     NaN    B
row2  C      D     E
row3  X     NaN    NaN

List_val = ['A','X']
```

The desired output is:

```
df_new = 
'id' 'col1' 'col2' 'col3
 row1  A     NaN    B
 row3  X     NaN    NaN
```

I tried the following:

```
df1 = df[df.columns.isin(List_val)]
```

It did not work. How to combine any and isin in one funciton ?

Thanks in Advance.

AP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and for check at least one `True` per rows [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with `axis=1`:

```
print (df.isin(List_val))
      id   col1   col2   col3
0  False   True  False  False
1  False  False  False  False
2  False   True  False  False

print (df.isin(List_val).any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool

df = df[df.isin(List_val).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
     id col1 col2 col3
0  row1    A  NaN    B
2  row3    X  NaN  NaN
```

If dont need compare `id` column simply [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) it:

```
df = df[df.drop('id', axis=1).isin(List_val).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
     id col1 col2 col3
0  row1    A  NaN    B
2  row3    X  NaN  NaN
```